# How can I specify assembly version for ASP.NET project on Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, version, visual-studio-mac

I am a newbie in programming with Visual Studio 2022 for Mac. Being used to Visual Studio for Windows, I could specify both Assembly Version and Assembly File Version with the Properties UI of the project itself.
Still, I can't find neither the UI nor an alternative way to do it in VS for Mac. So when using reflection and trying to retrieve the Version for the ASP.NET service, I always get 1.0.0.0.
I can change the Version value of both the project and the solution (or make the project inherit the solution's one) but I'm not able to get it programmatically.
How can I solve this versioning problem?
Is there a way to set the assembly version in code?
If not, is there a way to retrieve the Version information I can see in the VS for Mac project properties?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This seems to be due to the MAC environment .For example ,according to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/general/assembly-version-assembly-file-version) ,AssemblyFileVersion is displayed by Windows Explorer , and never used by .NET framework or runtime for referencing .There seems to be no substitute in MAC environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Chen, unfortunately this is something VS for Mac doesn't allow. After several hours of researching upon the matter I finally found the only way out. "Version" (Assembly Version) is an attribute that can be directly set as a tag into the "csproj" file (right click on the Project Name in Solution Explorer -> Edit Project File -> Insert "<Version>[major.minor.build.revision]</Version>" in "PropertyGroup" tag). After building it all, the reflection will give you the right assembly version. It's just a matter of setting it yourself directly into the XML. :/